# there are easy way to set / order 2d object depth in blender?

Tags: 2d, layers, depth-of-field

there are easy way button / shortcut / plugin
to set depth each object in blender?

TLDR: I need button / function like this:
[image]

Long Version:
I'm (try to) use blender for 2d animation, where I import SVG files from inkscape.
after adjusting SVG files so camera blender can see my object (by rotate all obj 90)

my SVG files shown like this.
[image]
when we see in perspective view we know that all object are in same coordinate Y

so I arrange all part one by one by

1. click object,
2. move object (to set Y)
3. put Y coordinate
4. back to no 1 for other object

since it a lot, I'm use shortcut

(select object by mouse) -> G -> Y -> 0.01 or 0.02 or -0.01 (depend depth)

so the result would become like this
[image]
With the way I did, sometimes when I have set [ear object] coordinate, when to move [hand object] coordinate, I realize that the previous object have wrong Y coordinate since no mater what, now my current object can't get perfect Y coordinate due to obstacle with previous object.
and now I have to set again previous Y coordinate. ( and it become mess when there are ton of object)

So there are a way to set order object easily like this button function give :
[image]
button / shortcut / plugin its okay as long its can make easy me to manipulate object depth for camera view.

Many Thanks before. sorry for the english

Comment: Congratulations on a very clear question.

Comment: i think (after reading it like 10 times) he wants to give all objects a y-Value and because he makes this very often, he wants an automatism that the "already changed"-y-value-objects are sorted by "already changed" ;)

Comment: @RobinBetts: your comment made my day!!!!! :D

Comment: Convert objects into Grease Pencil object ? GP works with layers, right?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question yet? I am struggling now with the same thing.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question yet? I am struggling now with the same thing. Adjusting the Y-axis position of objects by microscopic amounts is not a terribly elegant solution. Being able to reorder objects in the outliner and rendering them in that order would actually be a nice(r) solution.